# Can someone with poor coursework record but decent research profile fit in academia?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, grades, coursework

I want to try to enter academia by doing 2 postdocs after my PhD. However, I am bothered by the fact that I have been consistently poor/average in my grades during my undergrad, master's and PhD degree.

I had 3.2/4 GPA in undergrad. I had to retake 3 courses in my second year as I had flunked them. They were related to my current field of research.

My master's and PhD GPA were 3.75/4 each.

I had a bit of TA experience during master's and PhD. I took tutorials for a laboratory course for first and third year undergraduates.

Will my performance hinder my shortlisting for interviews in academia when I do apply for tenure track positions?

Comment: Your research surely matters more than your grades: A research candidate will be evaluated on their research, far more than their grades.

Comment: First, when you did a PhD (arguably also when you did a bachelors) you already entered academia. Next, why would anyone be interested in your undergraduate grades? Next, what is your country and grading system?

Comment: My undergrad was in India, grad school in the US.

Comment: Grades become important when there is nothing else that can be used as indicator of future performance. If your grades need to be considered for your postdoc application, you are already in a very weak position. Publications, your PhD thesis, talks and posters, letters of recommendation, the standing of your advisor and your alma mater should all be more important.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some effect but I'd expect it to be small and easily overcome. If you want a largely research position grades will be mostly irrelevant and you will be judged on the quality (and maybe quantity) of your research.

But even if you want a teaching position, you may have some insight into the troubles and travails of students that might serve you well. If you know what it is to work hard to overcome difficulties, I think you would be an asset.

Don't overthink it, and write the best applications you can, with good letters from the faculty.